# jQuery validator add method: custom messages

Tags: jquery, validation, methods, addition

I am using following code to show custom messages inside add method of jquery validation plugin. I referred this link: http://www.mainframes.co.uk/index.php/2011/04/07/jquery-form-validator-custom-validation-method-using-addmethod-for-validating-date-of-birth-dob/

```
$.validator.addMethod("nameId",function(value,element){

            var result = true;
        //check if pattern matches
                var pattern = new RegExp(<pattern>);                
            if(pattern.test(value)){            
                    //get availability via ajax call
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        async: false,   
                        "error":function() {   
                            alert("error");
                    }});
                    $.getJSON("<url>", 
                    {
                        param: value
                    },
                    function(data) {

                            if(condition){
                                result = true;
                            }else{
                                $.validator.messages.nameId = "Msg 1";
                                    result = false;                     
                            }
                    });

            }else{
                                $.validator.messages.nameId = "Msg 2";
                                result = false;                         
            }
    return result;
 },"");
```

This doesn't show any errors while validating. What could be wrong above...

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you put the .getJSON call inside of the success callback function of the .ajaxSetup? Like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("nameId",function(value,element){

    var result = true;

    var pattern = new RegExp(<pattern>);

    if(pattern.test(value)){            
        //get availability via ajax call
        $.ajaxSetup({
            async: false,
            "success": function() {
                $.getJSON("<url>", 
                {
                    param: value
                },
                function(data) {
                    if(condition){
                        result = true;
                    }else{
                        $.validator.messages.nameId = "Msg 1";
                            result = false;                     
                    }
                });
            },
            "error":function() {   
                alert("error");
            }
        });

    }else{
        $.validator.messages.nameId = "Msg 2";
        result = false;                         
    }
    return result;
 },"");
```

Comment: I still see same blank message (because the message at the end is ""). How to override this message with custom messages? Thanks!

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, I think the answers posted here cover the problem you describe: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/validation-plugin-changing-message-with-addmethod

Answer (score 1):

Add this just before your return result line:

```
$.validator.messages.myvalidator = customError;
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant have asynchronous callbacks inside a validation method.

Comment: Can you tell how to achieve this using remote, with multiple messages based on if/else condition. Thanks!